# AngualrJS with Karma - how do I write a unit test for a factory?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing a simple AngularJS 1.x web app.

I have a module:

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

factory.js

```
app.factory('DataFactory', function(){

  var DataService = {};

  DataService.something = function() {
    return 5;
  };

  return DataService;

});
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('DataController', function ($scope, DataFactory) {
    $scope.searchText = null;
    $scope.results = DataFactory.something();
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="DataController">
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="factory.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

test file:

```
  describe('Data Factory Test', function() {

    var Factory;

    beforeEach(function() {
      angular.module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function() {
      var $injector = angular.injector(['app']);
      Factory = $injector.get('DataFactory');
    }));

    it('is very true', function(){
        expect(Factory).toBeDefined();
      // var output = Factory.something();
      // expect(output).toEqual(5);
    });

  });
```

karma.conf.js:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app.js',
    'factory.js',
    'controller.js',
    'test/*.js'
]
```

How do I write a unit test to check if the factory exists, and to check the return of something?

I keep getting an error when i run karma start:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $controllerProvider

Edit: I got it working. How would I write the unit test for the controller with and without a factory?

Comment: Please post what you have in your test spec as well.

Comment: In the test - you have got `OlympicDataFactory` but in the code you are using `DataFactory` - with one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

First part shows how service / factory can be tested.
Second part show two ways of controller testing

- we just expecting that some variables from $scope have been changed
- we expect that some service / factory has been called

Probably all those kind of tests covers all our needs.

```js
angular.module('app', []).factory('DataFactory', function() {

  var DataService = {};

  DataService.something = function() {
    return 5;
  };

  return DataService;

}).controller('DataController', function($scope, DataFactory) {
  $scope.searchText = null;
  $scope.results = DataFactory.something();
});

describe('Data Factory Test', function() {
  var Factory;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_DataFactory_) {
    Factory = _DataFactory_
  }));

  it('is very true', function() {
    expect(Factory).toBeDefined();
    var output = Factory.something();
    expect(output).toEqual(5);
  });
});

describe('DataController ', function() {

  var $scope, instantiateController, DataFactory

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _DataFactory_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    DataFactory = _DataFactory_
    instantiateController = function() {
      $controller('DataController', {
        $scope: $scope,
        DataFactory: DataFactory
      })
    }
  }))

  // It shows that controller chenges $scope.results
  it('Calculates results', function() {
    expect($scope.results).toBe(undefined)
    instantiateController()
    expect($scope.results).toBe(5)
  })

  // It shows that DataFactory was called
  it('Calls `DataFactory.something`', function() {
    spyOn(DataFactory, 'something');
    instantiateController()
    expect(DataFactory.something).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 on the underscore notation. In case anyone wonder, `Underscore notation: The use of the underscore notation (e.g.: _$rootScope_) is a convention wide spread in AngularJS community to keep the variable names clean in your tests. That's why the $injector strips out the leading and the trailing underscores when matching the parameters. The underscore rule applies only if the name starts and ends with exactly one underscore, otherwise no replacing happens.`

Comment: Thanks for that! How would I write the unit test for the controller? Could you please add it to your answer?

Comment: Some proof of concept how controller can be tested have been added

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `angular.injector`:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  describe('Factory Spec', function() {

    var Factory;

    beforeEach(function() {
      angular.module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function() {
      var $injector = angular.injector(['app']);
      Factory = $injector.get('DataFactory');
    }));

    it('is very true', function(){
      var output = Factory.something();
      expect(output).toEqual(5);
    });

  });
  }());
```

To test a controller:

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
  });
});
```

From [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing);

Comment: I got an error: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $controllerProvider

Comment: It means that you haven't posted your entire code and there is a controller somewhere that needs to be mocked as well @user1261710

Comment: How would I do this for a controller?