# AngularJS with Karma - how would I write a unit test for the controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, karma-jasmine

Same code as: [AngualrJS with Karma - how do I write a unit test for a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815412/angualrjs-with-karma-how-do-i-write-a-unit-test-for-a-factory)

I'm not sure how to write a unit test for the controller.

How do you write one for the controller with the factory and how would you write it without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a controller unit test in AngularJS:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.num = 2;
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
      $scope.num += 2;
    }
  });
```

The test:

```
describe('myController', function() {
  var $scope;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myModule');
    inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $controller('myController', {
        '$scope': $scope
      })
    });
  });
  it('should increment `num` by 2', function() {
    expect($scope.num).toEqual(2);
    $scope.doSomething();
    expect($scope.num).toEqual(4);
  });
});
```

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "how would you write the unit test with the factory and how would you write it without?". Please explain more in a comment, and I'll update this answer. Good luck!